# Running FN Server on a Openshift Cluster without --privileged flag

Tags: openshift, root, fn

We are trying to deploy FN server in an Openshift Cluster without privileged security context, only enabling root mode (not privileged), but we are getting this error:

`

```
/usr/local/bin/preentry.sh: set: line 14: can't access tty; job control turned off
mount: permission denied (are you root?)
Could not mount /sys/kernel/security.
AppArmor detection and --privileged mode might break.
mount: permission denied (are you root?)
time="2022-12-09T12:03:59Z" level=info msg="Setting log level to" fields.level=DEBUG
time="2022-12-09T12:03:59Z" level=info msg="Registering data store provider 'sql'"
time="2022-12-09T12:03:59Z" level=debug msg="creating new datastore" db=sqlite3
time="2022-12-09T12:03:59Z" level=debug msg="mysql does not support sqlite3"
time="2022-12-09T12:03:59Z" level=debug msg="postgres does not support sqlite3"
time="2022-12-09T12:03:59Z" level=debug msg="mysql does not support sqlite3"
time="2022-12-09T12:03:59Z" level=debug msg="postgres does not support sqlite3"
time="2022-12-09T12:03:59Z" level=info msg="Connecting to DB" url="sqlite3:///app/data/fn.db"
time="2022-12-09T12:03:59Z" level=info msg="datastore dialed" datastore=sqlite3 max_idle_connections=256 url="sqlite3:///app/data/fn.db"
time="2022-12-09T12:03:59Z" level=debug msg="mysql does not support sqlite3"
time="2022-12-09T12:03:59Z" level=debug msg="postgres does not support sqlite3"
time="2022-12-09T12:03:59Z" level=info msg="agent starting cfg={MinDockerVersion:17.10.0-ce ContainerLabelTag: DockerNetworks: DockerLoadFile: DisableUnprivilegedContainers:false FreezeIdle:50ms HotPoll:200ms HotLauncherTimeout:1h0m0s HotPullTimeout:10m0s HotStartTimeout:5s DetachedHeadRoom:6m0s MaxResponseSize:0 MaxHdrResponseSize:0 MaxLogSize:1048576 MaxTotalCPU:0 MaxTotalMemory:0 MaxFsSize:0 MaxPIDs:50 MaxOpenFiles:0xc4201b5bf8 MaxLockedMemory:0xc4201b5c10 MaxPendingSignals:0xc4201b5c18 MaxMessageQueue:0xc4201b5c20 PreForkPoolSize:0 PreForkImage:busybox PreForkCmd:tail -f /dev/null PreForkUseOnce:0 PreForkNetworks: EnableNBResourceTracker:false MaxTmpFsInodes:0 DisableReadOnlyRootFs:false DisableDebugUserLogs:false IOFSEnableTmpfs:false EnableFDKDebugInfo:false IOFSAgentPath: IOFSMountRoot: IOFSOpts: ImageCleanMaxSize:0 ImageCleanExemptTags: ImageEnableVolume:false}"
time="2022-12-09T12:03:59Z" level=info msg="no docker auths from config files found (this is fine)" error="open /root/.dockercfg: no such file or directory"
time="2022-12-09T12:03:59Z" level=fatal msg="couldn't connect to docker daemon" error="Get http://unix.sock/_ping: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory"
```

`

Is there any way to deploy FN server without privileged mode?